# Scala named and default arguments in conjunction with implicit parameters

Tags: scala, default-value, named-parameters, implicits

Consider the following:

```
def f(implicit a: String, y: Int = 0) = a + ": " + y
implicit val s = "size"
println(f(y = 2))
```

The last expression causes the following error:

```
not enough arguments for method f: (implicit a: String, implicit y:
Int)java.lang.String. Unspecified value parameter a.
```

However, if you provide a default value to the implicit parameter a, there is no issue:

```
def f(implicit a: String = "haha!", y: Int = 0) = a + ": " + y
implicit val s = "size"
println(f(y = 2))
```

But the last line prints

```
haha!: 2
```

while I would have expected

```
size: 2
```

So the implicit value 's' is not picked up. If you instead don't provide any parameters to f and just call

```
println(f)
```

then the implicit value is picked up and you get

```
size: 0
```

Can someone shed some light on what's going on here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
println(f(y = 2, a = implicitly))
```

Once you start specifying parameters, you can't go back.  It's either the whole list is implicit or none of it is.

Answer (score 4):

Implicit parameters should go separately -- first, and in the end of method definition -- second. Like this:

```
def f(y: Int = 0)(implicit a: String) = a + ": " + y
implicit val s = "size"
println(f(y = 2))
```

Ouputs

```
size: 2
```

Comment: To use first default parameter must call `f()` .

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what jsuereth said, you could define your function as

```
def f(a: String = implicitly, y:Int = 0) = a + ": " + y
```

Or in the way I'm more used to seeing,

```
def f(y:Int = 0)(implicit a: String) = a + ": " + y
```

Comment: You should check which implicit scope that implicitly is using.  I don't think it's the same as the second option.